# How many times have the Stanley Cup Finals featured two Canadian teams?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl, stanley-cup

How many times have the Stanley Cup Finals been played between two Canadian hockey teams?

Comment: [List of Stanley Cup champions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Stanley_Cup_champions) at Wikipedia lists both finalists.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Since 1927](http://www.nhl.com/ice/page.htm?id=25426), when the NHL assumed possession of the Stanley Cup, there have been 8 instances of the Stanley Cup Finals consisting of 2 Canadian Teams.

> 1935 Montreal Maroons beat the Toronto Maple Leafs
>
> 1947 Toronto Maple Leafs beat the Montreal Canadiens
>
> 1951 Toronto Maple Leafs beat the Montreal Canadiens
>
> 1959 Montreal Canadiens beat the Toronto Maple Leafs
>
> 1960 Montreal Canadiens beat the Toronto Maple Leafs
>
> 1967 Toronto Maple Leafs beat the Montreal Canadiens
>
> 1986 Montreal Canadiens beat the Calgary Flames
>
> 1989 Calgary Flames beat the Montreal Canadiens